# Using modelForm hidden field with Formsets without using Crispyform.

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I am working with forms sets, I was wondering how one could use

`<input type='hidden'`

inside a form set. *(Django formsets allow us to use multiple forms instances of a single form)*

Its easy to do in normal single form where you just put the field with the `type='hidden'` and name='`fieldname`' e.g.

`<input type='hidden' name='user' value='{{request.user.id}}'>`

Dealing with `formsets` is a bit catchy, how to achieve the same behavior with the forms sets?

### Views.py

```
PictureFormSet = modelformset_factory(Picture, form=UpdatePictureForm, extra=0)
    formset_qset = Picture.objects.filter(id__in=[15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])
    if request.method == POST:
        ctx['form_set'] = PictureFormSet(request.POST, queryset=formset_qset)
        ctx['form_set'].save()

    ctx['form_set'] = PictureFormSet(queryset=formset_qset)

    return render_to_response('temp tabs.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, ctx))
```

### Template

```
 <form method="POST" action="" class="form-horizontal">

                {% for form in form_set %}
                    {{form.id}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                            {% with form.meta_data.value|load_meta_data as meta %}
                                <div class="portfolio-item video-container">
                                    <a class="" href="{% url 'view_image' form.id.value %}?in=pro">
                                        <i style="background-image: url({{ meta.image_size.thumbnail_small }});"
                                           class="ds-thumbnail-container"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            {% endwith %}
                        </label>

                        <div class="col-lg-8 ">

                            {{ form.name }}



                        </div>
                    </div>

                {% endfor %}
                {{ form_set.management_form }}

            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

### Explanation

Here in this code, We are rendering images from the database for editing there names. we have url information inside the `meta_data`, so we have selected

```
fields=['id', 'meta_data', 'name']
```

We want to change/Update the name, but not the `meta_data`

This code works fine for the most part, but how i want to keep one field unchanged for the modal?

I have `meta_data` field that I am using in the template, but i do not want that field to be modified, that value should be in the form like this

`{{form.meta_data}}`
This turns it into text area, with different name and id. and it expects it be changing. but i want to declare a hidden field and sets its value to the `form.meta_data.value`

If you have any questions regarding this please do not hesitate to ask. 
Thanks.